# MQPUT Message Length

Tags: visual-c++, ibm-mq

I have this function where I get a message from the queue

```
int MQGet(MQHOBJ Hobj,char* buffer,int* count, long waitInterval, MQLONG codePage)
{
    MQLONG  msgLen = 0;
    MQLONG  msgSize = *count-1;
    MQGMO   gmo = {MQGMO_DEFAULT};
    MQMD    md = {MQMD_DEFAULT};    /* Message Descriptor            */

    gmo.Options =   MQGMO_WAIT 
                  | MQGMO_SYNCPOINT
                  | MQGMO_ACCEPT_TRUNCATED_MSG
                  | MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
                  | MQGMO_CONVERT ;

    gmo.MatchOptions = MQMO_NONE;

    //md.Format = ???
    //md.CodedCharSetId = 850;
    md.Encoding = MQENC_NATIVE;
    if( codePage != 0 )
            md.CodedCharSetId = codePage;

    gmo.WaitInterval = waitInterval;

       MQGET(Hcon,                /* connection handle               */
             Hobj,                /* object handle                   */
             &md,                 /* message descriptor              */
             &gmo,                /* default options (datagram)      */
             msgSize,             /* message length                  */
             buffer,              /* message buffer                  */
             &msgLen, 
             &CompCode,           /* completion code                 */
             &Reason);            /* reason code                     */

    *count = msgLen;
   /* if (CompCode == MQCC_FAILED) {
        return (int) Reason;
    }*/    
    return (int) Reason;
}
```

and this on to put the message in the queue

```
int MQPut(char* queueName,char* buffer,int count, bool persist, MQLONG codePage)
{
       MQOD     od = {MQOD_DEFAULT}; 
       strncpy(od.ObjectName, queueName, (size_t)MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH);

       memcpy(md.Format,MQFMT_STRING, (size_t)MQ_FORMAT_LENGTH); /* character string format            */
       memcpy(md.MsgId,           /* reset MsgId to get a new one    */
              MQMI_NONE, sizeof(md.MsgId) );

       memcpy(md.CorrelId,        /* reset CorrelId to get a new one */
              MQCI_NONE, sizeof(md.CorrelId) );

//     memcpy(md.Encoding,        /* para forzar convert en destino */
//              MQENC_NATIVE, sizeof(md.Encoding) );
       md.Encoding = MQENC_NATIVE;

       if( persist )
           md.Persistence = MQPER_PERSISTENT; 


        if( codePage != 0 )
            md.CodedCharSetId = codePage;

//          memcpy(md.CodedCharSetId,        /* se agrega codificacion de caracteres a los mensajes */
//                codePage, sizeof(md.CodedCharSetId) );



 //      MQPUT(Hcon,                /* connection handle               */
 //            Hobj,                /* object handle                   */
 //            &md,                 /* message descriptor              */
 //            &pmo,                /* default options (datagram)      */
 //            count,               /* message length                  */
 //            buffer,              /* message buffer                  */
 //            &CompCode,           /* completion code                 */
 //            &Reason);            /* reason code                     */


             MQPUT1(Hcon,                /* connection handle               */
             &od, 
             &md,                 /* message descriptor              */
             &pmo,                /* default options (datagram)      */
             count,               /* message length                  */
             buffer,              /* message buffer                  */
             &CompCode,           /* completion code                 */
             &Reason);            /* reason code                     */


       if (CompCode == MQCC_FAILED) {
        return (int) Reason;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the problem I'm having right now is that I need to know what is the message's lenght exactly,

this is the RunGet and RunPut Service

```
void CNTService::RunPut()
{
    _finddata_t fdata;
    char searchPath[MAX_PATH];
    char fname[MAX_PATH];
    char inputFileName[MAX_PATH];
    char outputFileName[MAX_PATH];
    char* t;
    char* f;
    intptr_t findHandle;
    MQHOBJ Hobj;
    DWORD status;
//  long error;

    // Set the service running flag

    m_bIsRunning = true;

    // Send a debug message that the service has started

    DebugMsg("Entering CNTService::Run()");

    // Create the search path for the find first routines

    strcpy(searchPath,pathIn);
    strcat(searchPath,"\\*.");
    strcat(searchPath,inSuffix);

    // Process the incomming files from the search path

    while (m_bIsRunning) {
        try {
            // Connect to MQSeries 

            Hobj = 0;
            if ((status = Connect(qMgrName,connName,channelName)) != 0) {
                throw CError(MSG_MQSERIES_OPEN,itoa(status,conv1,10));
            }

            // Open the queue for writing

/*          if ((Hobj = OpenQueue(queueName,error)) == 0) {
                throw CError(MSG_MQSERIES_QUEUE,queueName,itoa(error,conv1,10));
            }
*/
            do {
                // get a file to process

                if ((findHandle = _findfirst(searchPath,&fdata)) != -1) {
                    do {
                        char* buffer = new char[fdata.size];  // Allocate memory space for the file contents
                        HANDLE ifile;
                        DWORD bread;

                        // Read the file to memory
                        sprintf(fname,"%s\\%s",pathIn,fdata.name);

                        // Open the file

                        //ifile = open(fname,O_RDONLY|O_BINARY);

                        ifile = CreateFile(fname,
                                           FILE_READ_DATA,
                                           0,
                                           NULL,
                                           OPEN_EXISTING,
                                           0,
                                           0);

                        if (ifile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                            // Read in it's contents to the memory buffered
                            if (ReadFile(ifile,buffer,fdata.size,&bread,0) == 0) {
                                DWORD err = GetLastError();
                                //l(ifile);
                                throw CError(MSG_OPEN_ERROR,fname,itoa(err,conv1,10));
                            }

                            // Close the file handle

                            CloseHandle(ifile);

                            // Check that the read byte coun is equal to the file size

                            if (bread != fdata.size) {
                                CloseHandle(ifile);
                                LogWarning(CError(MSG_FILE_SIZE,itoa(bread,conv1,10),itoa(fdata.size,conv2,10)));
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            LogWarning(CError(MSG_OPEN_ERROR,fname,itoa(GetLastError(),conv1,10)));
                            continue;
                        }


                        // Put the message into the MQSeries queue
                        //TODO: Recalcular tamaño del buffer
                        if ((status = MQPut(queueName,buffer,bread, persist, codePage)) != 0) {
                            throw CError(MSG_MQSERIES_PUT,itoa(status,conv1,10));
                        }

                        // Create the output file name

                        f = fdata.name;
                        t = inputFileName;
                        while (*f && *f !=  '.')
                            *t++ = *f++;
                        *t++ = 0;

                        sprintf(outputFileName,"%s\\%s%08d.%s",pathOut,inputFileName,GetTickCount(),inSuffix);;

                        // Rename the file to the queue directory

                        if (rename(fname,outputFileName) == -1)
                            throw CError(MSG_RENAME,fname,outputFileName);

                        // Free used heap 

                        delete[] buffer;

                    } while (_findnext(findHandle,&fdata) == 0);


                    // close the findfirst handle

                    _findclose(findHandle);
                }

                // Delay n milliseconds before processing the next request

                Sleep(delay);
            } while (m_bIsRunning);
        }

        // Trap thrown errors

        catch (CError err) {
           LogError(err);
        }

        // Trap unexpected errors

        catch (...)  {
           LogError(CError(MSG_SERVICE,"Error no esperado.",itoa(GetLastError(),conv1,10)));
        }

        // Close the queue handle

//      if (Hobj != 0) 
//          CloseQueue(Hobj); 

        // Disconnect from MQSeries

        Disconnect();

        // Delay for 5 seconds before reattempting to open MQSeries

        Sleep(5000);

    }


    // Debug message 
    DebugMsg("Leaving CNTService::Run()");
}

// Get messages from MqSeries queue and store them in the output directory

void CNTService::RunGet()
{
    char outputFileName[MAX_PATH];
    MQHOBJ Hobj;
    char tmpStr[512];    
    int count;
    long error;
    DWORD status;
    static int sequence = 0;

    // Initialize variables
    m_bIsRunning = true;
    // send a debug message theat the service is starting
    DebugMsg("Entering CNTService::Run()");

    // Set the localte to ascii
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"C");  /* for C with ancii 1 byte characters */

    // Process messages from the input queue
    while (m_bIsRunning) {
        try {
            // Connect to MQSeries
            Hobj = 0;
            if ((status = Connect(qMgrName, connName, channelName)) != 0) {
                throw CError(MSG_MQSERIES_OPEN,itoa(status,conv1,10));
            }
            // Open the input queue
            if ((Hobj = OpenGetQueue(queueName, error)) == -1) {
                throw CError(MSG_MQSERIES_QUEUE,queueName,itoa(error,conv1,10));
            }
            while (m_bIsRunning) {
                // Get the message from the input queue
                count = sizeof(buffer);

                error = MQGet(Hobj, buffer, &count, waitInterval, codePage);
                if (error == 0 || error == MQRC_TRUNCATED) {
                    int n;
                    int ofile;

                    // Log the file content to the system log 
                    sprintf(tmpStr,"count=%d,reason=%d",count,error);

                    if (logAll)
                        LogInfo(CError(MSG_SERVICE,outputFileName,tmpStr,""));

                    // Write the message contents to a file

                    sprintf(outputFileName,"%s\\MSG%08d%03d.%s", pathQueue, GetTickCount(), sequence, outSuffix);
                    sequence = ++sequence % 1000;

                    ofile = open(outputFileName, O_WRONLY|O_BINARY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT,S_IREAD|S_IWRITE);
                    if (ofile == -1) {
                        throw CError(MSG_OPEN_ERROR,outputFileName,itoa(GetLastError(),conv1,10));
                    }

                    n = write(ofile, buffer, count);
                    // Close the file
                    close(ofile);

                    // Check if the read in bytes differ
                    if (n != count){ 
                        throw CError(MSG_FILE_WRITE,itoa(n,conv1,10),itoa(count,conv2,10));
                    }else
                        MQCMIT();
                }else {
                        if (m_bIsRunning) {
                            if (error != MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE) {
                                sprintf(tmpStr,"Error MQSeries reason=%d, error=",count,error);
                                throw CError(MSG_SERVICE,tmpStr,itoa(error,conv2,10));
                            }
                            Sleep(delay);
                        }
                }
            } 
        }
        // Catch thrown errors
        catch (CError err) {
           LogError(err);
           //revertimos mensaje a la cola
           MQBACK();
        }
        // Catch unexpected errors
        catch (...)  {
            LogError(CError(MSG_SERVICE,"Error no esperado."));
            MQBACK();
        }
        // Close the queue handle
        if (Hobj != 0) 
          CloseQueue(Hobj); 

        // Disconnect from mqseries
        Disconnect();

        // Delay until the next attemp
        Sleep(delay);
    }
    // nothing more to do
    DebugMsg("Leaving CNTService::Run()");
}
```

If there is any body that could help out, I'll appreciate it.
Best regards

Comment: On top of Morags answer.. "if (error == 0 || error == MQRC_TRUNCATED) {" looks very dodgy to me - dont you mean MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_ACCEPTED or MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_FAILED... Be aware you are doing data conversion (GMO_CONVERT) and so you need to be aware of buffer handling - a good description of the problem is here (usually only a problem if you are handling dbcs characters)... https://hursleyonwmq.wordpress.com/2007/02/21/handling-truncated-messages/

Answer (score 2):

The output parameter on your `MQGET` call that you have named `msgLen` will tell you the actual length of the message. This is true even if the message was truncated on the get because the buffer you provided wasn't big enough. Thus allowing you to retry the `MQGET` with a bigger buffer.

Comment: Thanks for your reaply Morag, you're right, but the problem that i'm facing right now is, I have to give the buffer to the MQPUT based on the lenght of the message's content, for example my msg looks like this 

{{1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}{2:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}{4:
:27:1/1
:40A:IRREVOCABLE
:20:+++++
:31C:++++
:40E:XXXXXXXXXXXX
:31D:XXXXXXXXXXXX
:50:XXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXX...
-}
So, I need to read that msg and pass the lenght of it as the buffer lenght to the MQPUT, and there's where I have the problem, I don't know how to read the content's lenght.

Comment: Another comment is that we arre migrating from UNIX to LINUX so, in UNIX we don't have a problem because it accept whatever buffer size it has, but in LINUX you have to talk to the MQPUT the real lenght.

Comment: Is the message you are putting, the one you retrieved from the MQGET, or are you just doing the MQPUT on it's own? Any chance you could edit your question down to just contain what the problem is. It sounds like nothing to do with MQ in your above comment. It sounds like, "I have a buffer with some content in it and I don't know how long the content is". Also could you expand on the difference between UNIX and LINUX please. Both require the length of the message on the MQPUT call.